# array and parsing through sentence construction

Tags: javascript, html

I'm  really getting a hard time in running the parse button to show the result from the input box ...

these are my codes:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> sentence detector</title> </head>
<body background="english.jpg">
<font color="black">
<h1 align = center> TABLE OF WORDS </h1>
<br>
<h3>
<script>

var noun = new Array ("time", "year", "people", "way", "man", "day", "thing", "child", "Mr", "government", "work", "life", "woman", "system", "case", "part", "group", "number", "world", "house", "area", "company", "problem", "service", "place", "hand", "party", "school", "country", "point", "week", "member", "end", "state", "word", "family", "fact", "head", "month", "side", "business", "night", "eye", "home", "question", "information" , "power", "change", "interest", "development ");

   document.write("<b>");
   document.write("NOUN:    "); 
   for (i=0; i<noun.length; i++)
   {
   document.write(" " + noun[i] + "," + "   ");
    }
   document.write("<br>");
   document.write("<br>");
   </script>

<script>
 var verb = new Array ("allow","answer","arrive","ask" , "be", "become" , "begin" , "believe", "bring", "burn", "buy" , "call" , "can" , "decide", "describe", "destroy" , "die" , "do", "drink" , "drive", "eat", "end", "explain", "fall" , "feel" , "hope" , "hurt", "improve",  "jump", "know", "laugh", "learn", "leave", "lie", "listen", "live", "look" , "press" , "promise" , "pull" , "push" , "put" , "read" , "receive",  "recognize", "remember", "repeat" , "rest",  "return");

   document.write("<b>");
   document.write("VERB:     ");
   for (i=0;i<verb.length;i++)
   {
    document.write("    " + verb[i] + "," + "   ");
   }
  document.write("<br>");
  document.write("<br>");
```

```
 <script>
   var adj = new Array ("abandoned", "able", "absolute", "adorable", "adventurous", "academic", "acceptable", "adored", "advanced" , "afraid",  "belated",  "beloved", "beneficial", "better",  "best", "careful",  "careles" , "caring",  "circular", "classic", "clean", "clear" , "damaged" , "damp", "dangerous",  "dapper", "daring");

     document.write("<b>");
     document.write("ADJECTIVE:     ");
     for (i=0;i<adj.length;i++)
     {
        document.write("    " + adj[i] + "," + "    ");
      }
     document.write("<br>");
     document.write("<br>");
  </script>

 <script>
  var adv = new Array ("financially","willfully", "abruptly", "endlessly", "firmly", "delightfully",  "quickly", "lightly", "eternally", "delicately","wearily", "sorrowfully","beautifully","truthfully" ,"now", "first", "last", "early", "yesterday", "tomorrow", "today", "later", "regularly", "often", "never", "monthly", "always", "usually", "very", "too", "almost", "also", "only", "enough", "so", "quite", "almost", "rather", "back", "gamely", "helplessly" , "entirely", "absently",  "bodily", "bloodily", "boldly" , "crazily" , "heartbrokenly",  "healthily", "hurtfully");

document.write("<b>");
document.write("ADVERB:     ");
 for (i=0;i<adv.length;i++)
  {
    document.write("     " + adv[i] + "," + "   ");
   }
 document.write("<br>");
 document.write("<br>");
```

```
 <script>
    var prep =  new Array ("about", "above", "according to", "along with", "among", "apart from", "around as", "behind ","below", "beneath", "beside", "between", "beyond", "but", "by", "by means of", "concerning", "despite", "down", "except", "for", "excepting", "for", "in case of", "instead of", "into", "like", "near", "next of", "off", "on", "onto", "on top of", "out", "out of", "outside", "round since", "through", "throughout", "till", "under", "until", "up upon", "up", "to", "with", "within", "without");

 document.write("<b>");
 document.write("PREPOSITION:   ");
  for (i=0;i<prep.length;i++)
  {
    document.write("     " + prep[i] + "," + "  ");
  }
  document.write("<br>");
  document.write("<br>");
  </script>

  <script>
    var pronoun = new Array ("all", "another", "any", "anybody", "anyone", "anything", "both","each", "each", "other", "either", "everybody", "everyone", "everything", "few", "he", "her", "hers", "herself", "him", "himself", "his", "I", "it", "its", "itself", "little", "many", "me", "mine");

    document.write("<b>");
    document.write("PRONOUN:    ");
   for (i=0;i<pronoun.length;i++)
   {
     document.write("        " + pronoun[i] + "," + "   ");
   }
   document.write("<br>");
   document.write("<br>");
   </script>

   <script>
      var conj = new Array("for", "and", "nor", "but", "or", "yet", "so", "either", "or", "neither", "nor", "both", "and", "not only", "but", "also", "after all", "in addition", "next", "also", "incidentally", "nonetheless", "as a result", "indeed", "on the contrary", "besides", "in fact", "on the other hand", "consequently", "in other words", "otherwise", "finally", "instead", "still", "for example", "likewise", "then","furthermore", "meanwhile", "hence", "moreover", "thus", "however", "nevertheless");

      document.write("<b>");
      document.write("CONJUNCTION:  " );
      for (i=0;i<conj.length;i++)
      {
        document.write("     " + conj[i] + "," + "  ");
      }
      document.write("<br>");
      document.write("<br>");
      </script>

     <script>
        var interjection = new Array ( "Absolutely", "Achoo", "Ack", "Adios", "Aha", "Ahoy", "Agreed", "Alack", "Alright", "Alrighty", "Alrighty-roo", "Alack", "Alleluia", "All hail", "Aloha", "Amen", "Anytime", "Argh", "Anyhoo", "Anyhow", "As if", "Attaboy", "Attagirl", "Awww", "Awful", "Ay", "bam", "Bah", "hambug", "Begorra", "Behold", "Bingo", "Blah", "Bravo", "Brrr", "Bye", "Cheers", "Ciao", "Cripes", "Crud", "Darn", "Dear", "Doh", "Drat", "Eek", "Encore", "Eureka", "FiddlesticksFie", "Gadzooks", "Gee");

      document.write("<b>");
      document.write("INTERJECTION:     ");
      for (i=0;i<interjection.length;i++)
      {
        document.write("    " + interjection[i] + "! " + "," + "    ");
      }
      document.write("<br>");
      document.write("<br>");
      </script>

      <script>
         var deter = new Array ("the", "a", "an", "another", "no","some", "any", "my", "our", "their", "her", "his", "its", "each", "every" , "certain" , "its", "this", "that", "your", "whose", "little", "|ess", "least", "few", "fewer", "fewest");

          document.write("<b>");
          document.write("DETERMINER: ");
           for (i=0;i<deter.length;i++)
          {
            document.write("    " + deter[i] + "," + "  ");
          }
          document.write("<br>");
          document.write("<br>");
          </script>
         <br>
         <form>
         <center>
         <font size="+1">
            Input Words: <input type = "text" name  = "enter" size = "70"> 
         </form> 
             <input name="parse" type="button" value="parse?">
         </center>
         </font>
          </h4>
         </font>
         </body>
         </body>
         </html>
```

the output must be like this

1. choose from the words above
2. type it in the input box
3. click the button parse?
4. show results:

ex: she is mine

she-- pronoun

is-- preposition

mine-- pronoun

Comment: Can you also turn this into a jsfiddle please, so that we can run it? Most of the code you're showing can actually be trimmed down to get to the core of your problem (and you should do this. Show us a minimal example). On a JavaScript note: don't ever use `document.write`. It's an artifact from older JavaScript versions, and have very particular behaviour. Don't use it. Rewrite those scripts to either use `.innerHTML` to set content, or construct and append DOM elements.

Comment: Umm is this code from 1990? :)

Comment: @ThiefMaster It uses document.write, which [is used by W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_intro.asp) in its JavaScript introduction.

Comment: Oh great, w3schools again. That site so [needs to die](http://w3fools.com)... But anyway, `<font>` tags are not much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a couple of points to this:

You have your code directly in a couple of script tags, this means it gets executed immediately when the page gets loaded - and obviously this is before anyone can enter the text.

You need to wrap your code into some sort of a function that then gets called on input:

```
<script>
function parseWords() {
   //All of your code goes here
}
</script>
```

Then from your button you probably want to call this function I would assume when the 
button is pressed.

```
<input name="parse" type="button" value="parse?" onclick="parseWords()">
```

Your text input needs an ID so we can get the data from it easily:

```
<input id="textInput" type = "text" name  = "enter" size = "70">
```

Next you will have to get the data from the input and then split it up.

```
function parseWords() {
   var myText = document.getElementById("textInput").value;
   var myWords = myText.split(" ");
}
```

Now you have to loop over each of the words and find what type they are:

```
function parseWords() {
   var myText = document.getElementById("textInput").value;
   var myWords = myText.split(" ");

   for (int i = 0; i < myWords.length; i++) {
     // Check for your words here and generate the output
   }
}
```

This is not the full solution, but these are the major points I see wrong with your code. I hope you can figure out the rest from here.